# Краш без стактрейса

Tags: android, разработка-игр, libgdx

Приложение время от времени вылетает либо во время работы, либо при попытке развернуть в консоле следующая надпись:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3f490fe3 in tid 6640 (GLThread 37263)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении капать

На картинке ниже полный лог [image: Логи]
чуть выше примерно то же самое

Comment: полный stack trace покажите

Comment: Ух ты, аж сегфолт. Да с `libgdx`... Трейса, я полагаю, просто нет.

Comment: да вы правы его нет

Comment: вам придется как минимум рассказать, что это за проект, и что он использует